# Duplicate entry in MySQL slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5, duplication

I have a MySQL master-slave replication setup. When I checked `show slave status`, I got the result as `Slave_Sql_running:No` and last error as `Duplicate entry 'x' on query`.

But when I tried to delete the entry from that table result shown as `0 rows affected`.

I tried to fetch the record using select statement. Even then the result shown as `0 rows affected`.

Then I checked slave status again. The same state persists and the same error appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me start with a warning. Be very careful when you start messing with the data on the slave. It can really ruin the integrity of the replication setup.

That being said, if you are absolutely **certain** you don't want the slave to execute that particular statement, you can issue the following commands on the slave:

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL sql_slave_skip_counter=1;
START SLAVE;
```

This will skip the next statement in the replication log and move on. Here's the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-global-sql-slave-skip-counter.html) for reference.